# Navigation Controller in presented view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm new to IOS programming. I would like to ask about how to instantiate a navigation controller in the presented view. This is how I instantiate my navigation bar from previous view.

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = self.revealViewController;

    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = (id) revealController.frontViewController;

    if ( ! [frontNavigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[CalibrateViewController class]]) {
        CalibrateViewController *promotionViewController = [[CalibrateViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:promotionViewController];
        [revealController setFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [revealController revealToggle:self];
    }
```

But when I wanted to do it with present view ,

```
LoginViewController *promotionViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:promotionViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I did not know what to put in when i wanted to instantiate using presentView.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Sorry for the confusion. Basically I wanted to do something like this:

1. I got a main view, let's name it viewA which will call out a viewB.
2. viewB then will change into viewC.
3. Lastly when I dismiss my viewC, it will back to viewA.
4. All of the view will have navigation controller in it.

And ya, here is the navigation button created later on "viewB", "viewC".

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];

[revealController panGestureRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;


//check if whether to use barTintColor instead of tintColor. (IOS difference)
if (IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {
    // here you go with iOS 7
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x808080);
}
else
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x808080);
}

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
//=======================================================================================
```

It gives the error on the view that instantiating the navigation button.
The error looks like this :
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: so now what you need is after dismiss viewC, you need to go back to viewA.?

Comment: The problem now is I can't even instantiate the navigation button although I had instantiate the bar. It gives error like "*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil" and I don't know what is missing.

Comment: is it okay if i code a sample where you will have 3 screen you will navigate from 1-> 2 ->3 ->1 and all this will have navigation controller in it.?

Comment: sure, but I need that navigation button instantiate just like what I update my question. (Standardize)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can present a navigationcontroller on a specific viewcontroller

```
LoginViewController *promotionViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
[navigationController pushViewController:promotionViewController animated:YES];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, but I need it to direct to the LoginViewController with navigation controller. If according to your code, it's bringing me to the SWRevealViewController which a totally black screen (in my case).

Comment: It helps but still got error when instantiating the navigation button in the "viewB" page.

Comment: Updated in question. Really need help ><

Answer (score 0):

try out the following code in place of your code:

UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = (id) revealController.frontViewController;

```
  if ( ! [frontNavigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[CalibrateViewController class]]) {
        CalibrateViewController *promotionViewController = [[CalibrateViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:promotionViewController];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [revealController revealToggle:self];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically Presentmodelviewcontroller doesn't have navigation controller we need to code it please follow below code

```
NextViewController *ivc= [[NextViewController alloc]init]; // here you are allocation your next viewController
UINavigationController *naviCtrl =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: ivc]; // here you are allocation navigation controller for your next viewController
[self presentViewController:naviCtrl animated:YES completion:nil];   // here you are presenting your next view controller
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, but I need it to direct to the LoginViewController with navigation controller. If according to your code, it's bringing me to the SWRevealViewController which a totally black screen (in my case).

Comment: so you just want to move back to your previous view controller?